# Java Android , HttpGet error - Host name may not be null

Tags: java, android, uri, host, http-get

I am using HttpGet to get the contents of some images. It has worked well but now it gives me errors with a new server I am using which returns images on the form of:

https://amx-sfs.qpass.com/d/da/207b3f6f-4fda-4faf-b7ae-a186530e1245

The error is **Host name may not be null**

I have researched and it seems that the error is common when underscores appear on the URL, however my URL only contains hyphen which i think is accepted by URI. Anyway i also tried using the following to escape the url with no success:

```
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(new URI(null,item.getImageUrl(),null));
```

What else can be causing the problem and how can i solve it?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I first tried directly with the Url using

```
new HttpGet(item.getImageUrl())
```

Then I also tried with 4 args:

```
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(new URI("https","amx-sfs.qpass.com",item.getImageUrl().substring(25),null));
```

With the same result, even if I debug the HttpGet Object, and watch the URI object it has, the host property appears ok (amx-sfs.qpass.com) , but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there was no Java or Android problem, it results that the server changes the request when it comes from a device...

Answer (score 0):

Did you encode URI? For example remove spaces or other special characters that break stuff? 
Try android.net.Uri.encode(String s)

HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(new URI(null,android.net.Uri.encode(item.getImageUrl()),null));

Best way to debug this to always print the URL and analyze the ones that give an error.

Comment: The URL That I posted is the one that is giving the error, encoding it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong constructor.  The three argument URI constructor has this signature:

```
public URI(String scheme, String ssp, String fragment)
```

but you are providing a URL as the 2nd argument rather than an SSP.  I think you should be using the one argument constructor that takes a URL string as its argument.

Comment: Well I firstly used the one argument constructor with no success and I tried then the 3 arg and the 4 arg with the same result. See my Edit.

Answer (score -1):

Please try a host name without the use of hyphens "-" or underscores "_", see if it works .