# IllegalArgumentException in Android

Tags: java, android, exception

I am using the following code to obtain an Http Response in an Android app.

```
 HttpGet get = new HttpGet(targetURL); 
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
 String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

But  `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);` is throwing an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null`

Any help on what is going wrong?

Comment: What does the URL look like?

Comment: It means that whatever `targetURL` you use, it's not valid because it doesn't have a host defined like www.google.com. Please check your `targetURL`

Comment: i think you should use http:// at start of your targetURL

Comment: Ok targetURl = "localhost:8080/.../../..=" + string + "&..=" + string;  It is an API call.

Comment: URI's always need a scheme. Try `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Try encoding your URL

Comment: I added http:// in front of the URL. Now it is throwing 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'

Comment: Don't perform long-running (for example network) tasks on the UI thread, use AsyncTask instead. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @KenWolf Thanks! I'll follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "scheme" part of your URI. All URIs require a scheme:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Syntax

> The URI syntax consists of a URI scheme name (such as "http", "ftp", "mailto", "crid" or "file") followed by a colon character, and then by a scheme-specific part.

Add `http://` on to your String, so make it `http://localhost:8080`

`HttpGet` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the URI is invalid, so that's exactly what is happening.

[HttpGet documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html#HttpGet%28java.net.URI%29)

Answer (score 0):

From 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html#HttpGet%28java.lang.String%29

Your targetUrl is invalid. So maybe the String is wrong. Another possibility is the answer to:

[Java Android , HttpGet error - Host name may not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554630/java-android-httpget-error-host-name-may-not-be-null)

There the problem was that the request was changed by the server when it came from a mobile device.